# How to overwrite global sass variables of a shared component within a yarn monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, monorepo

I've recently setup a yarn monorepo, which includes a package "shared-ui", written in react, which holds all shared components that are used within several other next.js based packages of the monorepo.

(My overall setup is pretty much identical to the one from this medium post: https://medium.com/frontend-digest/using-nextjs-in-a-monorepo-e011ff1826f5)

The component within the package "shared-ui" looks as followed:

```
import React from "react"
import styles from "./Button.module.scss"

const Button = ({ className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <button className={`${styles.global} ${className}`} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  )
}

export default Button
```

Another package within the monorepo imports it and adds some custom styles.

```
import styles from "./index.module.scss"

export default function Home() {
  return <Button className={styles.button}>Hello World</Button>
}
```

Now the shared-ui includes a bunch of sass variables like "@primary-color", which I'd love to be able to generally overwrite in some way within the importing packages. Right now the above setup only allows me to basically overwrite such global variables via a bunch of additional code / scss.

So to keep it short, is there some way to overwrite global variables as "@primary-color" of the shared ui by defining them within the importing package somehow?